# How to I find lowest and highest value of this array (java)

Tags: java

Here is my current code cannot get it to work. Will not print out correct values. Currently, prints out Highest as 2897 and also prints out lowest as 2897.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] salesfigures2014 = {2200,1951,2181,2888,3084,2897};
    int [] salesfigures2015 = {2359,2099,2352,2952,3274,3264};
    String [] salesfiguresmonths = {"Jan","Feb","March","April","May","June"};  

    int Average2014 = avgsales2014(salesfigures2014);
    int Highest2014 = highmonth2014(salesfigures2014,salesfiguresmonths);
    int Lowest2014 = lowmonth2014(salesfigures2014,salesfiguresmonths);
    //int Average2015 = avgsales2015(salesfigures2015);
    //int Highest2015 = highmonth2015(salesfigures2015,salesfiguresmonths);
    //int Lowest2015 = lowmonth2015(salesfigures2015,salesfiguresmonths);
    //int AverageSales = avgmonth(salesfigures2014,salesfigures2015,salesfiguresmonths);

    System.out.println("highest sales in 2014: " + highmonth2014(salesfigures2014, salesfiguresmonths));
    System.out.println("lowest sales in 2014: " + lowmonth2014(salesfigures2015, salesfiguresmonths));


}

public static int avgsales2014(int[] salesfigures2014) {

    int i, total = 0; 
    for(i=0; i<salesfigures2014.length; i++)            
    {
        total = total + salesfigures2014[i];     

    }
    total = total/salesfigures2014.length;
    return(total);

}
static int highmonth2014(int[] salesfigures2014, String[] salesfiguresmonths) {

    int high = salesfigures2014[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < salesfigures2014.length; i++){
        if(salesfigures2014[i] > high );
        high = salesfigures2014[i];
    }
    return high;
}
static int lowmonth2014(int[] salesfigures2014, String[] salesfiguresmonths) {

    int low = salesfigures2014[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < salesfigures2014.length; i++){
            if(salesfigures2014[i] < low );
            low = salesfigures2014[i];
        }
        return low;
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the semicolons after your if statements inside your for-loops

Comment: Also, you should indent the lines that set the high and low, for readability purposes.

Comment: I would suggest simply using [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html).

Comment: For traversing an array, you should start for loop with i=0, not i=1

Comment: @Emre Sülün This is incorrect for his logic!  Why would he want to compare the first element of the array with the first element of the array??? Obviously neither will be larger or smaller.  He sets `i=1` in this instance because he already has the value of `salesfigures2014[0]`....

Comment: Good example of why you should always use curly braces with if statements, avoid simple errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of those extra (and wrong) `;`s.

[image]